# How to handle "critical" REST API call failure?

Tags: django, api, rest

I am creating a mobile app that will interact with a django back-end api.  I want to add ability for app user to change some "critical" account attributes via the app, with call to back-end.  Eg, change username, which is used now to authenticate with back-end on each call.  The success path is simple, but I'm concerned about some failure along the way that leads the app and back end to be out of sync.  Eg, user invokes username change on app, the username is successfully updated on the back-end, but something fails and the app never gets a response.  So app now is left not knowing if old username still intact or new username is now at back-end.  Just wondering if there is any standard pattern for making this type of thing bulletproof.  Same scenario holds for password change via app.

Only thing I can think of now is keep both usernames in app until app can confirm current state of back-end...

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern called "post exactly once" semantics that may be what you're looking for. (See Mark Nottingham's [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-poe-00) for a proposed implementation of this pattern.) It incurs overhead, but for cases when you want to guarantee that a request was processed exactly once, it's appropriate.

The problem is that there, as of yet, isn't a standard way to do this, so using it will (somehwat) couple your client and server together with out-of-band knowledge.